# Detect broken connection in SQL Server 2012 on the client side

Tags: c#, sql-server, keep-alive

We are developing a C# program for connecting with a database and sending some packets to the database, then storing the data into the database. C# program and SQL Server are on two separate computers, and we want to ensure that connection between C# program and SQL Server is always established. If this connection is broken, we must try again to connect to SQL Server.

But we have some problems:

1. After establishing connection, if we stop SQL Server, the client side (C# program) is not notified of the closed connection. After sending a packet from client to SQL Server, we detect broken connection.
   **Note**: we don't like to loose any packets
2. If we unplug the Ethernet cable between the two computers, the client side will notice the broken connection after sending a packet, after approximately 20 seconds, and in this interval we may loose several packets.

Is there quicker and reliable methods to detect broken/closed connection in SQL Server?

Comment: Thanks @marc_s for editing.

Comment: Any idea (Solution)?